# Unable to Save email in the Activity History

Tags: javascript, webservices, class, singleemailmessage, send-email

**I have a custom button to send an email. The code is working fine. Now I would like to insert those email in the activity history. I did set     mail.setSaveAsActivity(true). But when I click the button it is showing the error** as:

[image]

I am unable to resolve this.Any help is appreciated. The following is my code.

```
global class memberApproval {

webservice static boolean callApproval(Id localId) { 
            set<Id> Uid = new set<Id>();
            String grpId = Label.GroupId;
     List<GroupMember> Lst =[Select Id, UserOrGroupId From GroupMember Where GroupId =: grpId];
     if(Lst.size()>0){
     opportunity opp =[select id,owner.email from opportunity where Id =:localId];
     for(GroupMember g:Lst){
         Uid.add(g.UserOrGroupId);
     }

     if(Uid.size()>0){
     List<User> Lstuser = [select id,email from user where Id In:Uid];
     if(Lstuser.size()>0){

     List<String> EmailIds = new List<string>();


     for(User u:Lstuser){
     EmailIds.add(u.Email);
     }
       //New instance of a single email message
         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        // Who you are sending the email to

           mail.setToAddresses( EmailIds  );
        String templateIdVal= Label.TemplateId;
       String[] bccEmail = new String[]{opp.owner.email};

           // The email template ID used for the email
           mail.setTemplateId(templateIdVal);
           mail.setTargetObjectId(userinfo.getuseriD());
           mail.setwhatid(opp.id);
           mail.setBccSender(true);
           mail.setBccAddresses(bccEmail);
           mail.setUseSignature(false);
           mail.setReplyTo(opp.owner.email);
           mail.setSenderDisplayName('Confirmation of Order Quote');
           mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);  

        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
     }
     }
     }
    return true;               
}
```

}

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This argument `setBccAddresses` and `setToAddresses` is allowed only when a template is not used. Please remove that and try again. 
`setTargetObjectId` will itself resolve the recipient list based on the email template you have provided.

Comment: Emails are working perfectly using the template. Both the to address recipient and BCC recipient are getting emails. My issue is I would like to add this email to activity history so that user will make a note of it if he checks in the activity history before sending another email.

Comment: I understand your point. I am saying, if you are using templateId, then ONLY use targetObjectId, which accepts ID of the contact, lead, or user to which the email will be sent. setSaveAsActivity will work only when targetObjectId is used. 
If not using a template, then you should use setHTMLbody to create the body and setToAddresses to create recipient list. Therefore I told you to either use targetObjectId OR setToAddresses, but not both together.
This is may be causing the error.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_base.htm#apex_Messaging_Email_setSaveAsActivity

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setTargetObjectId